# How do I turn off the prompt to launch in safe mode?

Tags: firefox, windows-10

When holding `shift` and opening Firefox in safe mode, an annoying prompt shows up.  How can I get it to open up in safe mode but without any prompt?

I've tried [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/951221#answer-410557), which suggests setting `toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes` in `about:config` to a high number.  However, the problem still persists.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish i want to open in safe mode without prompt

Comment: Great, I just edited your question so that's worded a little more clearly.

Comment: You might also tell what operating system you are running such as Windows 7, 8, 10, etc. assuming it's Windows. The link refers to Windows 8.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish sorry, win10